# How can i add more function

Tags: android, image, view

i want to click on any image and go anything i want.
Example: i click on item 3 then, then there is a big image display in the screen. 
Please kindly help me to add more code about this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a View.onClickListener to do that:

```
final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)  {
         ... add your code here...
    }
}; 

imageView.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

It is difficult to be more accurate as you didn't tell how your layout is made.